# remove this light blue glow around mat form field

Tags: css, angular-material, mat-form-field, mat-input

how can I remove this light blue glow around my matInput inside  mat-form-field?
[image]

I'm not sure if what property I need to override and I have no idea how to go about this, I tried searching but couldn't find anything.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I already posted an answer but it would be nice if you provided some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your **CSS**:

```
input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```